# How do I ask about "remaining time"?

Tags: questions, colloquial-language

Let's say the cooking time for a dish is 50 minutes. I want to ask how much time remains between now and when the dish will be done.

What is the right way to ask that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say

> When will the dish be ready?
>
> After how much time will the dish be ready?

```
***Not a native speaker.***
```

Comment: The first answer looks good.  The second one isn't wrong, exactly, but it feels non-fluent.  "How much time is there before the dish is ready?" might be a better phrasing, or maybe "How long until the dish is ready?" if you're speaking informally?

Comment: yea, I've mentioned I am not a native speaker.

Comment: *When will the dish **be** ready? It's a question, and the subject comes before the auxiliary, but otherwise that's a good expression, it sounds quite polite too.

Comment: okay, I've edited it.

Answer (score 1):

How much time is left until the (dish) is ready?

There are other ways to say it, but this is pretty general.

Answer (score 1):

I think these two examples will do it for you:

> How long before it's ready?
>
> How much longer before it's ready?

Answer (score 0):

You could go about it a couple of ways.  One would be to straight up ask what you basically already said:

> How much time remains for [insert action/activity/etc. here]?

Or you could say something along these lines:

> How much longer will this take?

You could (if you wanted) replace "this" with whatever thing you're asking about.

> How much longer will the dish be cooking?